# How to read last updated rows in Google Spreadsheets API v4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm currently using the Google Spreadsheets API V4 to read a spreadsheet. It works fine, I read and write through it and the changes are immediately reflected in the Google spreadsheet. However, I want changes I make through the web browser to be reflected in my app as well. I can't see any events in the API, and I can't find any way to do it in Google either.

The spreadsheet is relatively large (1500+ rows), so I can't constantly check every single cell for a change.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an onEdit trigger that will log the edit date and other details in another sheet inside the same spreadsheet.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```